# ALL requests returning as Forbiddden 403 after implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-security

I just added WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to my project to try and make an user logic (login - password - what which user could do to my application) for the first time ever but something is really wrong.

Whenever I try to make a request, to any path or any kind of method, it returns me as 403 Forbidden! I don't know what to do since this is the first time I'm dealing with any kind of security logic.

this is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean
        AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider
                     = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
            return  provider;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN") 
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/tools")
                .hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

        }

  
}
```

I also have these two classes (I'm following a tutorial and the guy made these two):

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Users user;

public CustomUserDetails(Users user) {
    super();
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getLogin();
}

public String getEmail() {
    return user.getEmail();
}


@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

and

```
    public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Users user;

    public CustomUserDetails(Users user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getLogin();
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

if I left anything out and you really wanna help, this is the entire code: https://github.com/vitoriaacarvalho/backend-challenge-very-useful-tools-to-remember-

I'm already thanking (so much) anyone who responds and tries to help!

Comment: Hi there! 403 usually means that the user don't have the required permissions, in this case the authority/role required to access a resource.

Comment: and you have enabled debug logging and read what your logs are telling you u assume

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code, you do not set the user's privileges in the service that returns user information.

You have created a user in UserService and specified only the id information. In this case, you cannot access any of the urls you have given to the role.

If you edit your code as below, your problem will be solved.

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserRepository repo;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<Users> user= repo.findByLogin(login);
    if(user==null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }
    //return new CustomUserDetails(user.get());
    return new User(login, login, Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")))
}
```

}